# Synchronise a props in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm trying to synchronize a prop between a parent and child in [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js).

I have a parent component that includes a child component with a prop. When the prop changes in the parent, the prop is updated in the child and when the prop changes in the child, the parent is updated.

I started with this example:

The html where my component is mounted

```
<div>
   <div id="app">
   </div>
</div>
```

And the parent + child:

```
Vue.component('myinput', {
   template: '<div><input v-model="mytext" /></div>',
   props: ['text'],

   data() {
      return {
         mytext: this.text
      }
   }
})

const vm = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   template: '<div> <myinput :text="mytext"></myinput> <p> {{mytext}} </p></div>',

   data() {
      return {
         mytext: "Hello World!"
      }
   }
});
```

Since I cannot mutate the props, I need a local copy [[Example Codepen]](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mMJGZO?editors=1010).

If I want my parent component to be updated when the child change, I need to `$emit` the value.

For that, I created a wrapper around `mytext` in the child component:

```
computed: {
     wrapperMyText: {
       get() {
         return this.mytext;
       },
       set(v) {
         this.mytext = v;
         this.$emit('update:text', v);
       }
     }
```

I use wrapperMyText in the model. [[Example Codepen]](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GvJYgm?editors=1011)

Now, if I want the binding the other way (parent to child) I need to add a watcher in the child.

```
watch: {
     text(v) {
       this.mytext = v;
     }
   },
```

[[Example Codepen]](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZJGqeN?editors=1011).

In the example, there is only one prop, I need to create a watcher and a computed property. If I have 5 properties, I will need 5 watchers and 5 computed properties. That means the component code is polluted (too much code) with all this stuff. So my questions are:

Is this the standard pattern to sync a prop?
Is it better in this case to use a Store (like vuex)?
Why is so much code necessary to do a simple case?

After reflection, it seems I'm trying to re code v-model with properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single computed property will accomplish everything you are attempting.

```
Vue.component('myinput', {
   template: '<div><input v-model="wrapperMyText"></div>',
   props: ['text'],
   computed: {
     wrapperMyText: {
       get() { return this.text;},
       set(v) { this.$emit('update:text', v);}
     }
   }
})
```

Here is your [updated pen](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/VzLgYa?editors=1010).

So to answer your questions:

1. This is a standard pattern.
2. If you put the state in Vuex, your input component will no longer be re-usable.
3. You don't need all that code.

Comment: He asked a same question yesterday and i commented with a fiddle because I could not completely understand the question. He said he solved it as the issue was something else. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45323183/7814783 .....+1 :)

Comment: Hello @VamsiKrishna Maybe it was looking the same question but it was not :) I start learning Vuejs, so I confuse a lot of thing for now. Thanks for commenting anyway