# Re-render component without killing the perfs

Tags: javascript, performance, vuejs2

This question is linked with [Synchronise a props in Vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345366/synchronise-a-props-in-vuejs)

The solution given as an answer works perfeclty. But in the case or the child component have a lot of data, the performances are killed because Vuejs rerender the component.

Here is the reproduced issue:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MvwRgo?editors=1011

```
Vue.component('myinput', {
   template: '<div><input v-model="wrapperMyText"><div v-for="item in toto">{{item}}</div></div>',
   props: ['text'],
   data() {
      return {
         toto: new Array(100000)
      }
   },
   computed: {
     wrapperMyText: {
       get() { return this.text;},
       set(v) { this.$emit('update:text', v);}
     }
   }
})

const vm = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   template: `
      <div> 
         <myinput :text.sync="mytext"></myinput> 
         <p> {{mytext}} </p>
         <button @click="myclick">OK</button>
      </div>`,

   data() {
      return {
         mytext: "Hello World!"
      }
   },

   methods: {
      myclick() {
        this.mytext = 'Foobar'; 
      }
   }
});
```

How can I keep the same behavior without killing the performances ?

Comment: This is a component composition issue. If, for example, your input was a child component of this component with its thousands of rows of data (which is by itself bad design, no one can digest thousands of rows of data), then re-renders would be limited to the input. By placing the data in the same scope you are forcing everything to re-render.

Comment: To be more accurate, in my case, the child contain a "select" (instead of the input in the example).  The options of this select are a big list (fetched by ajax). I want my parent to be updated when the select change. But if I use the design of the example, the big list is rerender. In this particulary case, what would be the good design ?

Comment: What's a large number of values? If it's more than 30ish, in my opinion a select really starts to become unusable and I would develop a different kind of control to pick an option. Some kind of autocomplete option is the typical approach.

Comment: It's about 1400 entries. I used select for a "POC" but I will definively go to an autocomplete component, thanks